# Different log files for different DJ workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have various DJ workers, and each worker works on a single queue. I want the logging for each queue to go in a separate file. How can I do that?

I start the delayed job workers using script/delayed_job. Currently, I set my custom log file which is set in config/initializer/delayed_job_config.rb with the command:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("log_file")
```

I don't think I can modify the initializer file for a specific logger because it is called before the Worker is initialized by script/delayed_job. Any idea how I can do this?